How to use correct type hinting where a function returns a list of lists where each inner list contains exactly 3 strings
If my Python function returns a list of lists, with each inner list containing precisely 3 strings, how should I specify this with type hints?
Below is my initial approach:
from typing import List

def foobar() -> List[List[str]]:  # Indicates that the return value is 
    # a list where each element is another list of strings.
    return [["str1", "str2", "str3"], ["str4", "str5", "str6"]]

Now the problem with the above code is it doesn't explicitly indicates that the function foobar is returning a fixed length of 3 strings inside the list.
I tried this code:
from typing import List, Tuple


def foobar() -> List[Tuple[str, str, str]]:  # Indicates that the return value is
    # a list where each element is another list of strings.
    return [["str1", "str2", "str3"], ["str4", "str5", "str6"]]

But as you can guess the above code does work but it seems wrong since my function is returning a list of lists not a list of tuples and type hint we use should match the actual data structure returned by the function.

Why don't you return a list of tuples? Lists are mutable, so their length isn't part of their type.

@jonrsharpe yeah i just found it out myself that python doesn't support specifying length of lists in type hinting unfortunately i can't return a list of tuples so i would have to go with my initial approach instead.

Make a class with 3 string properties. Return a list of those?

@OneCricketeer yeah that makes sense too
